# How do I make sure the helpers and models reload in RSpec when I'm using Spork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, helper, rspec-rails, spork

It seems like my helpers (and sometimes my models) aren't being reloaded on each run with Spork. What should I be putting into my "Spork.each_run" block?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, so I set this in my each_run block:

```
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
  ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
  FactoryGirl.reload

  Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'app', 'helpers', '*.rb')].each do |file|
    require file
  end
end
```

Also, don't forget this in your config/environments/test.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = !(ENV['DRB'] == 'true')
```

Comment: This works for me: my helper is reloaded. But it results in a strange failure of a controller test: `Failure/Error: 
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       ArgumentError: prepare called on a closed database: rollback transaction
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'`

Comment: Yes same for me @JoshuaMuheim, did you fix?

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you load them in the *prefork* block. If you load the stuff there, your test run faster, but sometimes you need to reload. You could load on the "each_run" block, but test would be slower. If you prefer speed, you can restart the Spork server when you see that you need the reload. This way, the *prefork* block will run again and your models and helpers will be reloaded.

Comment: OK, if I wanted to reload a particular set, would I just require it normally?

Comment: I think so, just put it in the each_run block.

Answer (score -3):

I never had these problems, and maybe it's because I'm also using the Guard gem like described in Ryan Bates' RailsCast?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork